# How to make this script animated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll

I have a scrolling script, how to make animated it? (make it smooth)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.event.props.push("wheelDelta");
        $( '#lololol' ).on( 'mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function ( e ){
            var delta = e.wheelDelta || -e.detail;              
            this.scrollLeft += ( delta < 0 ? 1 : -1 ) * 120;
            e.preventDefault();
        });
});
```

Comment: I found a little bit another way to fix this.
Now, need to wait 10 hours cause of <10 reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace this line

```
this.scrollLeft += ( delta < 0 ? 1 : -1 ) * 120;
```

with

```
$(this).animate({
    scrollLeft: $(this).scrollLeft() + ( delta < 0 ? 1 : -1 ) * 120
});
```

Optionally, you can specify second parameter for the `$.fn.animate` function to provide variable animation time.
More info [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Answer (score 0):

You can animate the scrolling by animating the `scrollLeft`-property using the `animate`-function of JQuery `$elem.animate({ scrollLeft: value }, durationMs, 'easeFn', callbackFn)`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.event.props.push("wheelDelta");

    $('#lololol').on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var delta = e.wheelDelta || -e.detail;    
        var scrollLeft = $(this).scrollLeft() + (delta < 0 ? 1 : -1) * 120;

        $(this).animate({ scrollLeft: scrollLeft }, 500, 'swing', function() { 
            // callback fn
        });
    });
});
```